# Reply received after timeout when using multiple RabbitTemplate objects

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a Java Spring Boot 1.5.10 application that I am connecting to two different RabbitMQ servers with.  One RabbitMQ server is running on the same host as the Spring Boot application and the other is on a different/remote host. 
 This version of Spring Boot includes org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.7.6.RELEASE, by the way.  So, here is some of my configuration code that pertains to the local RabbitMQ server:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory(host);
    factory.setVirtualHost(vhost);
    factory.setUsername(username);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setChannelCacheSize(2);

    // Add a custom client connection property, which will show up in the Admin UI (useful for troubleshooting).
    factory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().getClientProperties().put("Connection Type", "Local");

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory,
        MessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin admin(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    rabbitAdmin.afterPropertiesSet();
    rabbitAdmin.setAutoStartup(false);
    return rabbitAdmin;
}
```

And here is some of my configuration code for a RabbitMQ server running remotely on another host:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory remoteConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory(remoteHost);
    factory.setVirtualHost(remoteVhost);
    factory.setUsername(remoteUsername);
    factory.setPassword(remotePassword);

    // By default, only one Channel will be cached, with further requested Channels being created and disposed on demand.
    // Consider raising the "channelCacheSize" value in case of a high-concurrency environment.
    factory.setChannelCacheSize(3);

    factory.setConnectionThreadFactory(new CustomizableThreadFactory("RemoteRabbit-"));

    // Add a custom client connection property, which will show up in the Admin UI (useful for troubleshooting).
    factory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().getClientProperties().put("Connection Type", "Remote");

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin remoteAdmin(ConnectionFactory remoteConnectionFactory) {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(remoteConnectionFactory);
    rabbitAdmin.setIgnoreDeclarationExceptions(true);
    return rabbitAdmin;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory remoteContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory remoteConnectionFactory,
        MessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter) {

    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(remoteConnectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    factory.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false); // on error, don't put back in the queue
    return factory;
}
```

Now comes the good part.  I have another RabbitTemplate that I am calling convertSendAndReceive() on which is configured with the remoteConnectionFactory.

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate payTemplate(ConnectionFactory remoteConnectionFactory,
        TopicExchange fromExchange, MessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(remoteConnectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyAddress(fromExchange.getName() + "/" + buildMyBindingKey());
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(30000L);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer payReplyContainer(ConnectionFactory remoteConnectionFactory,
        RabbitTemplate payTemplate, Queue fromQueue) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(remoteConnectionFactory);
    container.setQueues(fromQueue);
    container.setMessageListener(payTemplate);
    return container;
}

@Bean
public TopicExchange fromExchange(RabbitAdmin remoteAdmin) {
    TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange("some.from.exchange", true, false);
    exchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(remoteAdmin);
    return exchange;
}

@Bean
public Queue fromQueue(RabbitAdmin remoteAdmin) {
    Queue queue = new Queue("myReplyQueue");
    queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(corporateAdmin);
    return queue;
}

private String buildMyBindingKey() {
    return "someBindingKeyHere";
}
```

My problem occurs when I call convertSendAndReceive() on the payTemplate.  The reply is received fine, but it almost seems to be received twice.  This worked when I was connecting to only one RabbitMQ server, but after configuring connections to two servers, I get this:

```
2018-06-11 18:29:57,156|WARN||payReplyContainer-1|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate|||||Reply received after timeout for 1

2018-06-11 18:29:57,165|WARN||payReplyContainer-1|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler|||||Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:949)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:902)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:790)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:105)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:208)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1349)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:760)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1292)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1262)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:105)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1518)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Reply received after timeout
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.onMessage(RabbitTemplate.java:1759)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:899)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Again, the payTemplate does get the reply/response it was waiting for, but its like the container received another message that no one was waiting for.  I'm stumped.   Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried turning on DEBUG logging and follow the message flows? What is on the other side (responding to the sendAndReceive) ? Since you are using a topic exchange, is it possible there are two queues/consumers bound to the exchange?

Comment: Gary, you nailed it.  It was a bit further "downstream", but I had 2 shovels that were both copying data from 1 exchange to another exchange.  Well, that type of configuration produces this temporary queue between the 2 exchanges, and the messages were being duplicated (the exchange was of type fanout).  I've since changed that exchange to fanout to a single queue and let the shovels pull from that single queue so those temporary queues do not get created.  But, your answer to look for an exchange with two consumers (2 shovels in this case) bound to the same exchange was spot-on.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidDiehl, you are good to answer to your own question and accept it. That's indeed was a problem and you have a reasonable solution. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it was an exchange (an extra binding that shouldn't have been there) that was responsible for duplicating the response.  Much thanks to Gary for reviewing my code and presumably seeing nothing wrong and suggesting some things to look at.